# How do I truncate a table via linked server using a synonym for the table name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server, synonym, sp-executesql

I know I can do the following:

```
EXEC Server_Name.DBName.sys.sp_executesql N'TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table_name'
```

But what if I want to use a synonym for the table?

I'm on SERVER1 and I want to truncate a table on SERVER2 using a synonym for the table name.

Is this possible?

Comment: can you change the marked answer as it's simply a link that doesn't work anymore, so there is no valuable information there.

Answer (score 3):

My workaround was using the synonyms table to lookup underlying table name, then running a dynamic SQL statement. It is documented that synonyms cannot be used with TRUNCATE, but at least this is a decent workaround.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(500) = (SELECT TOP 1 base_object_name
    FROM Server_Name.DBName.sys.synonyms WHERE name = 'table_name')
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'EXEC Server_Name.DBName.sys.sp_executesql N''TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @TableName + ''''
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Stored Procedure in Server2 Database for Truncate Tables then call the Stored Procedure from Server1.

Like this:

```
EXEC [Server2].[DBName].[SchemaName].sp_TruncateTable;
```