# Issue truncating a table over linked server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that truncates the first table on our data warehouse, then copies data from our local database to the DWH server.

Here's the code:

```
USE [ARGTPAWN-DB-DWH].[DWH].[dbo].[PML];
GO

TRUNCATE TABLE [ARGTPAWN-DB-DWH].[DWH].[dbo].[PML];
GO

SELECT *
INTO [ARGTPAWN-DB-DWH].[DWH].[dbo].[PML]
FROM [14TPAWNDB001].[FLMedicaid].[dbo].[PML]  
GO
```

And the response I am getting is:

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Database 'ARGTPAWN-DB-DWH' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
>
> Msg 4701, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Cannot find the object "PML" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
>
> Msg 117, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   The object name 'ARGTPAWN-DB-DWH.DWH.dbo.PML' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

The servers are already linked, so that is not an issue, but I'm very curious as to why this is not working.

Comment: in what database does this procedure exist?

Comment: Your SQL makes no sense at all. First of all, where is the stored procedure? You're treating everything as a table/view so it's unclear. Also the first line is completely invalid, do you know what `USE` does?

Comment: are you trying to execute a stored procedure that truncates a table over linked server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I truncate a table via linked server using a synonym for the table name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822751/how-do-i-truncate-a-table-via-linked-server-using-a-synonym-for-the-table-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked Server and distributed query can be tricky in term of performance...

You should consider to write the Stored Procedure on the database that hosts the target tables even if you call it from the database that hosts the source tables.

On target database :

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [DBO].[TARGET_SIDE_PS]
 AS

 -- For error handling.
 DECLARE @aERROR int
 DECLARE @aCOUNT int

 -- Start transaction.
 BEGIN TRANSACTION

 -- Drop target table.
 IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.PML', 'U') IS NOT NULL
 DROP TABLE dbo.PML;
 -- Error catching
 SELECT @aERROR = @@ERROR, @aCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT
 IF @aERROR<>0
 BEGIN
     -- Error : do what is needed.
     -- 
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
     RETURN 1
 END

 SELECT *
 INTO dbo.PML
 FROM [SOURCELINKEDSERVER].[SOURCEDATABASE].[dbo].[PML] 
 -- Error catching
 SELECT @aERROR = @@ERROR, @aCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT
 IF @aERROR<>0
 BEGIN
     -- Error : do what is needed.
     -- 
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
     RETURN 2
 END
 IF @aCOUNT <= 0
 BEGIN
     -- No data: do what is needed.
     -- 
     PRINT 'NO DATA !!'
 END
 COMMIT TRANSACTION
 RETURN 0
```

Call the target side PS from the source side (or from the target side) and it's done but **source side database have to be linked to target side database.**
Transaction can be remove due to DROP/CREATE/INSERT sequence.

You can do the oposite : PS on the source side, with drop and insert on the linked target side server database, but you must know :
- transaction will take a while.
- all the source data will be locked during the whole process.
- INSERT will take a while.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to execute:

```
USE [ARGTPAWN-DB-DWH].[DWH].[dbo].[PML];
```

Simply execute the lines below.

Answer (score 0):

What is `ARGTPAWN-DB-DWH`? If this is the server name it is not needed.

Your `USE` statement should refer to the database only.

Your `SELECT * INTO...` will attempt to create the table PML, if this already exists (which it will if you are performing a truncate) it will fail - Use `INSERT INTO...` or `DROP TABLE...` instead of truncate.

Don't use SELECT *.

Comment: i think it's a linked server

Comment: It is a linked server.