# Can't truncate table in linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I'm trying to truncate table on remote linked server:

```sql
truncate table [REMOTE-SRV].[FL].[tmp].[reg];
```

However, I get the error:

> Cannot find the object "reg" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

In linked server properties I'm connecting with `sysadmin` permissions:

[image]

`srvadmin` is `sysadmin` in `REMOTE-SRV`:

[image]

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Unless I recall incorrectly, and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) hasn't been updated, `TRUNCATE` cannot be used against a linked server (it only supports 3 part naming). You'l need to use a different method, such as a deferred statement (as shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14822751/2029983)).

Comment: you can execute the command at the server, like: exec('truncate table [FL].[tmp].[reg]') at linkedServerName